# Merge together previous characters if found special characters in a list

Tags: python, list

How would I merge together previous characters in a list if found a special characters or multiple special characters.

For example

```
L = [ "a", "b","c", "-", "a", "b", "c", "-" "a", "b", "c", "-"]
```

to

```
L = [ "abc", "-", "abc", "-" "abc", "-"]
```

Comment: What is the desired output for `L = ["a", "b", "-", "-", "c", "d", "-", "e", "f"]`?

Comment: I would just like to merge all the previous characters if found a special character like "-"  in the list

Comment: So "e" and "f" should remain separate because they are not previous to any special characters?

Comment: what is hanging you up? pseudo code wise it seems pretty straight forward, loop through chars, if letter then concat to current item, else make a new one then another for new current

Comment: oh it would be L = ["ab", "-", "-", "cc", "-" "e"]

Comment: where did the `"f"` go?

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

L = [ "a", "b","c", "-", "a", "b", "c", "-", "a", "b", "c", "-"]
result = []
for is_special, v in itertools.groupby(L, lambda c: c=="-"):
    if is_special:
        result.extend(v)
    else:
        result.append("".join(v))

print result
```

Replace `c=="-"` with whatever criteria you use to judge "special characters". Result:

```
['abc', '-', 'abc', '-', 'abc', '-']
```

Comment: I guess this is the faster and better approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

For the given string and the required output you can try

```
>>> JoinedL = ''.join(L)                  # Join the string
>>> import re
>>> output = re.split('(-)', JoinedL)     # Split the string based on '-'
>>> output.remove('')                     # Remove the '' at the end
>>> output
['abc', '-', 'abc', '-', 'abc', '-']
```

And for Kevin's e.g

```
>>> L = ["a", "b", "-", "-", "c", "d", "-", "e", "f"]
>>> JoinedL = ''.join(L)
>>> output = re.split('(-)', JoinedL)
>>> output.remove('')
>>> output
['ab', '-', '-', 'cd', '-', 'ef']
```

The algorithm is to join the list and then split based on `-`. But we use `re` here as we need to retain the delimiter.

Links to the docs -

- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)

Comment: I don't think `'ef'` should be grouped since it's not before a `'-'`

Comment: @SirParselot I did wait for the OPs answer to Kevin's comment. His reply was ambiguous. Hence I waited for an answer. I have modeled my answer to match Kevin's output. I'd delete it if the OP thinks otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

More simply:

```
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', '-', 'a', 'b', 'c', '-', 'a', 'b', 'c', '-']
L = [x for x in "".join(values).replace('-','*-*').split('*') if x]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only combining letters that are before a `'-'` you could use

```
L = ["a", "b", "-", "-", "c", "d", "-", "e", "f"]
result = []
s = ''
for i in L:
    if i == '-':
        if s:
            result.append(s)
        result.append(i)
        s = ''
    else:
        s += i

if s:
    result += list(s)

print result

['ab', '-', '-', 'cd', '-', 'e', 'f']
['abc', '-', 'abc', '-', 'abc', '-']
```